# Next13 - Trying to add search query into next url along with middleware | Please use only absolute URLs - error

Tags: next.js, middleware, i18next

Actually i was trying to create a server-side carousel component by help of app route.
so if you take a look at how im handling it:

```
import Image from "next/image";
import React from "react";
import ArrowRight from "/public/assets/icons/landing/arrowright.svg";
import Link from "next/link";

interface Props {
  id: number;
}

const testimonials = [
  // an array
];

const Testimonials = ({ id }: Props) => {

  const generateRoute = (type: "forward" | "backward") => {
    if (type === "forward") {
      if (id < testimonials.length) {
        return `/?testimonialId=${+id + 1}`;
      }
      return `/?testimonialId=${0}`;
    }
    if (type === "backward") {
      if (id == 0) {
        return `/?testimonialId=${+testimonials.length}`;
      }
      return `/?testimonialId=${+id - 1}`;
    }
    return ''
  };

  return (
    <div className="mt-[56px] mb-[32px] bg-[#01164D] w-full  flex justify-center items-center">
      <div className="w-full max-w-[1216px] p-10 relative grid grid-cols-1 items-center lg:items-start gap-[24px] lg:ps-[308px] xl:ps-[274px]">
        {/* image */}
        <div
          className="absolute left-[50%] top-0 translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] 
           lg:top-[50%] lg:left-auto lg:right-[24px] xl:right-0 lg:translate-x-0"
        >
          <div className="relative w-[64px] h-[64px] lg:w-[250px] lg:h-[360px] ">
            <Image
              src={testimonials[id || 0].image}
              fill
              className="object-fit rounded-[50%] lg:rounded-[8px]"
              alt="pesare"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        {/* comment */}
        {/* the guy */}
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-[4px] lg:row-start-2 lg:items-start">
          <h2 className="text-[16px] text-white font-bold leading-6">
            {testimonials[id || 0].guy}
          </h2>
          <h3 className="text-[14px] text-white">{"مدرعامل هلدینگ ثابت"}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="bg-quotes bg-no-repeat bg-right-top ">
          <p className="text-[14px] font-light mt-[24px] text-white kg:text-start lg:max-w-[660px]">
            {testimonials[id || 0].content}
          </p>
        </div>
        {/* buttons */}
        <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-[20px] lg:justify-start">
          <Link
            href={generateRoute("forward")}
            className="bg-white py-[10px] px-[8px] rounded-[4px] cursor-pointer"
          >
            <ArrowRight />
          </Link>
          <Link
            href={generateRoute("backward")}
            className="bg-white py-[10px] px-[8px] rounded-[4px] rotate-180 cursor-pointer"
          >
            <ArrowRight />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Testimonials;
```

So as you can see im adding a search parameter for handling the shown testimonial's id.
and im recieving the id from props which that prop is recieved from search parameters of page.

and also im using i18 so there is a need for a middleware like this:

```
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import url from 'url'

import { i18n } from "../i18n-config";

import { match as matchLocale } from "@formatjs/intl-localematcher";
import Negotiator from "negotiator";

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const pathname = request.nextUrl.pathname;

  // // `/_next/` and `/api/` are ignored by the watcher, but we need to ignore files in `public` manually.
  // // If you have one
  if (
    request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/_next") ||
    request.nextUrl.pathname.includes("/api/") ||
    PUBLIC_FILE.test(request.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return;
  }

  // Check if there is any supported locale in the pathname
  const pathnameIsMissingLocale = i18n.locales.every(
    (locale) => !pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) && pathname !== `/${locale}`
  );

  // Redirect if there is no locale
  if (pathnameIsMissingLocale) {
    const { searchParams } = request.nextUrl
    const search = searchParams.toString()

    const locale = 'fa'
    const redirectUrl = url.format({
      pathname: `/${locale}${request.nextUrl.pathname}`, 
      search
    })

    return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl) 
  }
}

export const config = {
  // Matcher ignoring `/_next/` and `/api/`
  matcher: ["/((?!_next).*)"],
};
```

So untill now every thing is ok.
but when i try to add a serach parameter to my app even with changing the route by hand this error shows up:

[image: See the error message]

i dont know what else can i do, ive tried some other middleware functions but non of them solved the issue.

if you know how can i handle this middleware to consider search parameters and get rid of that error, that would be a favor if you let me know.

Comment: Whats the value of `redirectUrl` before you do the redirect?

Comment: Like the error says, you cant use relative urls in middleware. You need to use absolute url.